# How to authenticate Jetty websocket client for spring websocket (JSR-356)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-websocket, jetty-9, java-websocket

We have Spring websocket [STOMP and JSR] at server side and Jetty websocket client to communicate with server. Authentication works fine from browser as we authenticate user on login, we have sockjs STOMP at browser side, but we need authentication at Jetty websocket client also.

How to do that?
Any other option?

Comment: @Bruno, i think  jetty websocket client doesn't provide a way to authenticate during the connection

Comment: How do you authenticate user? If it's cookie, you can retrieve some session id like JSESSONID from cookie set by server by performing login action using Jetty's HTTP client and set it to WebSocket handshake request e.g. [ClientUpgradeRequest](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.2.9.v20150224/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/client/ClientUpgradeRequest.html).

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-authentication

Comment: Thanks @DonghwanKim, we are using basic authentication for websocket. As you said I have added basic auth header to ClientUpdradeRequest. :)

Comment: @Kunal Congrats. If you face such issue again, then compare each WebSocket handshake requests' traffic using Wireshark, Fiddler or something. If you do that this time, you would find there is no authentication request header in Jetty's WebSocket handshake request. And that's the cause you should fix. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify Basic authentication in spring auth configuration

```
<security:http auto-config="true" pattern="/websocket" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="ajaxAwareAuthenticationEntryPoint" disable-url-rewriting="false">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:http-basic/>
</security:http>
```

Jetty websocket client SSL configuration along with user authentication

```
URI serverURI = new URI("wss://domain:port/websocket");
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
URL url = classLoader.getResource("resources/domain.jks");
SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();  
Resource keyStoreResource = Resource.newResource(url);
sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreResource(keyStoreResource);
sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("Keystore Password");
sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword("Keystore Password");   
WebSocketClient webSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(sslContextFactory);
ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
request.setSubProtocols("xsCrossfire");
String basicAuthHeader = HttpBasicAuthHeader.generateBasicAuthHeader("username", "password");
request.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + basicAuthHeader);
webSocketClient.start();
// Websocket class (@WebSocket annotated)
SecureClientSocket socket = new SecureClientSocket();
final Future<Session> connect = webSocketClient.connect(socket, serverURI, request);
```